# Do we create a relation for supporting entity in database design?

Tags: database-design, relational-database

Suppose we have

```
Drinker(SSN, name, address)
Beer(name, manf)
```

We also want a supporting entity that connects `Drinker` to `Beer` called `Likes`

1. Is this the right schema?  Likes(**SSN**, **name**, **manf**) as name and manf are the keys of `Beer`.
2. Do we actually create `Likes` in the database? I was told that there were three methods to convert an E/R diagram into relational database relations.

   a) straightforward E/R diagram

   b) Object-Oriented approach

   c) Null method

With (a), the text book said that we can just skip `Likes`.

I am confused. Can someone help me?

Comment: is manf really a key for beer? Seems like a manufacturer (if I read that right) could have multiple beers. Second, if it's a one to one relationship, you could simply have Drinker { SSN, Name, Address, BeerID} and then have Beer {BeerId, Name, etc..}. If I could like many beers then you want a relationship table Likes { BeerID, SSN } where BeerID and SSN make the primary key. Altneratively, you could add additional fields to the Likes table, something like order, so that you could say Dave Likes Beer1 the most, and beer2 second most.

Answer (score 1):

The reason your textbook may have said that you could skip the `Likes` table in an ER diagram is that in a conceptual or logical ERD many-to-many relationships can be represented by a line instead of a box (assuming your ERD notation uses lines for relationships and boxes for tables).

In a *physical* ERD, you would have to represent the many-to-many relationship between `Drinker` and `Beer` using an **intersection entity** - in this case your `Likes` table.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is many-to-many relationship, then yes: `Likes` would be a separate table containing in its primary key the combination of primary keys from `Drinker` and `Beer`.

I've never seen this skipped in real databases. Generally, your goal should be to enforce as much integrity as you can in the database itself (as opposed to in client applications), and *declaratively* (as opposed to, say, triggers).